# Minimal portlet environment for developing?

Tags: liferay, portlet

At our company we are using Liferay for portals. My biggest issue with developing for such a huge framework is that the restart takes a lot of time even on a decent PC. We're trying to use hot deploying were it's possible but this sometimes just doesn't work (dependencies require restart, PermGen space errors occurs sometimes and Liferay have to be killed, etc.)

What i'm thinking about is that with most of our portlet's we are not really using any Liferay specific services just the JSR 168 provided things which is a standard. So i'm wondering if there's any minimal portlet environments available for Jetty or Tomcat which we can use for quicker portlet development? Of course i know that once i encounter a Liferay specific service call this is not an option.

I was testing [Apache Pluto](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/) earlier which is a full blown but still lightweight portlet container however it works differently the way the portlet wars are assembled (web.xml should be modified) and it breaks compatibility in our build environment with Liferay. So it's not an option but i'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used life ray portal, but too much played with GateIn portal because IBM Portal is heay, mostly for quick development on JSR-286 i used gatein

Currently used for visioneo.org, very flexible for every kind of use, large community.

Here is short summary

**Liferay**  Currently used for visioneo.org, very flexible for every kind of use, large community.

**eXo Platform**  Awesome look and set of web applications embedded. Last generation portal, very impressive! Based on Gatein

**JBoss EPP** Based on gatein, and designed to work with JBoss middleware architecture

**Gatein**   A great portlet container. Light weight, easy to use. But unlike Liferay and eXo, it does not ship with collaborative portlets (Forum, Wiki etc.)

**uPortal**   Beautiful portal, though its CSS are very intrusive: some BIRT styles are broken by uPortal's css.

**Pluto**  Not really a portal, Apache Pluto can be used as a development / test platform. Often considered as a reference for portlet specifications.

**Jahia** Great look however not based on standards: portlets are supported but not really highlighted, a specific module technology is used instead

Comment: Thanks. I've also found that Pluto has an embedded mode. This can be relatively easily integrated with an embedded Jetty to create a one-click-to-run/debug development environment: http://portletwork.blogspot.hu/2007/08/launching-and-debugging-portlets-from.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [JRebel integration for Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/community/projects/jrebel/overview). There's an [introduction Webinar](https://www.liferay.com/video?title=video-web-event-Improving-Efficiency-With-Portal-Development) available, I don't know if it fully applies to the current implementation (the webinar is a bit aged) but it will give you an idea of the product/project.